# Should we schedule a meetup in chat?

Tags: discussion, community, chat

Would you be interested in a scheduled meetup in [our chat site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/jewish-life-and-learning)?

The goals would be to give people who are interested a way to get to know each other outside the relatively narrow content of the main and meta sites and to raise awareness that the chat site exists for this and other purposes.

If we should have it, what time of week and day should we have it?

Comment: By the way, it would be cool if more people would lurk there when they can. If there are enough people hanging around, it'll be a lot easier for spontaneous conversations to happen from time to time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've since implemented [Parashat Hashavua' Chat](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/parashat-hashavua-chat), which fits this bill quite nicely. I have a feeling that quite a few people have gained awareness of the chat room and its features as a result, as well as gotten better acquainted with each other.