# Parashat Hashavua' Chat

Tags: discussion, chat, events

Our [first](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/513/parashat-hashavua-chat) Parashat Hashavua' ([weekly Torah portion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weekly_Torah_portion)) Chat, despite the fact that it was advertised only minimally, turned out to be a lively, interesting [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/parashat-hashavua-chat-1-vayishlach-5772). So, why not do it again every week?

- **Where**: The Mi Yodeya [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam)
- **When**: Wednesdays at 17:30 UTC (20:30 in Israel; 13:30
  in New York; 12:30 in St. Louis)
- **Notifications**:

  - You can get a doodad for your calendar [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468/jewish-life-and-learning?tab=schedule) if you're into that sort of thing.
  - You can also register there, and the system will send you a reminder each week.
  - For six hours preceding the chat, a "Warmup" is scheduled to remind people (via auto-generated site banner) that the chat is coming. Feel free to get a head start of posting topics to talk about during this period.
- **What**: Freewheeling conversation related to each week's [Torah
  Portion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weekly_Torah_portion)
- **Why**: People like to talk about the Parasha.
- **Transcripts**: Chat transcripts will be stored [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468/jewish-life-and-learning?tab=conversations). Most recent: **[#30 - D'varim 5772](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/parshat-hashavua-chat-30-dvarim-5772)**

Comment: Sounds great! Just a small note: It's scheduled for every seven days. You might wish to cancel specific instances of it (that come out on _yom tov_ or, perhaps, even _chol hamoed_ or before _yom tov_ if there's no _parashas hashavua_).

Comment: @msh210 Yeah. We'll cross those bridges, as well as the shift to DST, when we come to them.

Comment: Last time the chat only lasted an hour. Perhaps we should keep the discussion open for most of the day, so everyone has time to get their two cents in at some point. And people can pop in and out of the chat room when they have time.

Comment: @jake, I think that we should keep the discussion open for a long time for the reason you suggest, but we should also have a particular designated meeting  time. A lot more chat happens when a bunch of people are in the room at the same time. How about a 1-hour main chat, preceded and followed by 6-hour "open house" periods?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Time to cross the DST bridge...

Comment: Re crossing that bridge, see chat starting at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3907385#3907385.