# Can you design a Community Promotion Ad for Parashat Hashavu'a Chat?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, chat, design, advertising

As reported [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/567/2), we have, for a limited time, the ability to create [Community Promotion Ads](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) to help build awareness for some of our regular site promotions, and how well we utilize this nee tool is going to be watched closely.

So, I'd like to get a head start on ads for the features that we had in mind when we asked for this tool.

Can you design an ad for [Parashat Hashavu'a Chat](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/parashat-hashavua-chat)?

[There's an official official place to post ads](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/567), but let's use *this* post to bounce some ideas around at various levels of development. As shown on the official ads post, an ad consists of:

- An image file that's 220 x 250 pixels
- A tagline to show when someone mouses over the ad
- A URL to send a person to who clicks on the ad (presumably [Parashat Hashavua' Chat](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/parashat-hashavua-chat), in this case).

What should be in the image?

What should the tagline be?

Please post anything from fragmentary concepts to polished graphics.

Comment: Does the parshat hashavu'a chat have a dedicated chat room?  Yesterday it looked to me like it was the regular chat that we designated for a particular purpose for a couple hours.  If somebody clicks that ad on a Monday, will he just see the regular chat?  Do we need to create a dedicated chat room so that at least he'd see the previous week's chat, and meanwhile not other discussions?  (I don't know how chat rooms work so don't know if this makes sense.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio, Right now, we're using the general chat room. I actually think it's valuable to cross-mingle general site chat and the Parasha chat so that people who come for either have an opportunity to become aware of the other, but I and the community could possibly be convinced to move it to a dedicated room if you make a convincing meta post to that effect. The URL that I'm proposing for the ad is actually to the meta post announcing the recurring chat and pointing people to the chat room. Unless we make a dedicated room, I think this is the only logical target.

Comment: In general I agree with the cross-mingling; it's only the interaction with the ad that's giving me pause here.  But maybe a link to the meta post about it addresses that, particularly if that post contains a link to the start of the most recent chat so our hypothetical Monday visitor can get a sense of what it's like and then set a reminder for Wednesday.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks for that idea about maintaining a link to the most recent chat transcript in the announcement. It's worthwhile regardless of the ad situation, so I've implemented it.

Comment: Thanks for adding the link!  I think that'll help a lot (and yeah, not just for the ad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a design concept:

Three cartoon talking bubbles stacked one on top of the other, with their tails pointing in alternating directions (e.g. right, left, right).

- Join us for Parashat Hashavu'a Chat
- Every Wednesday in the Judaism.SE chat room
- Click here for details

Comment: [Prototype.](http://i.imgur.com/83tAS.png)

Comment: @msh210 Thanks. Yes, that's what I had in mind.

Comment: ...but more artistically executed. `:-)`

Comment: ...now at http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/586.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a graphics person, but for the Parshas Hashavua chat, we could put a picture of a shabbos table with a caption "Be Prepared".