# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1414/community-promotion-ads-2013)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for Jewish life and learning
- interesting in-site activities and events
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/567).

Comment: Highest voted ads meeting the threshold (and the other technical requirements) are automatically used? Or does a human pick?

Comment: Once an ad meets the threshold it will automatically be included in the rotation.

Comment: See also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/560 and http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/562.

Comment: what happens after February 23?

Comment: @avi We'll evaluate the effectiveness of this privilege and then we'll get back to you. :)

Comment: Quick, someone tell the guy with the Tallit shop to post an ad here!

Comment: @avi, some more fitting candidates might be resources we use here, like hebrewbooks.org, chabad.org, mechon-mamre.org, etc.

Comment: This still seems to be in use.

Comment: @IsaacMoses http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1331

Comment: Aarthi, @RebeccaChernoff, can there be something in quotes after the [1] or [2] URL, so it will appear onmouseover in the ad?

Answer (score 9):

[image: Join us for Parashat Hashavua' Chat every Wednesday in the chat room.]

Comment: This is meant to replace the old ad, whose design clashes with the new site design. Anyone who voted on the old one, please downvote it. (I'll delete that answer as soon as this one has enough votes to display om the main site.)

Comment: Did some tweaking, see the change history notes.

Comment: @Naftali - To reply to your comment on the old ad (which I'm deleting now), we discussed this in chat and decided to go with a new ad, rather than "steal" the votes from this one.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Hebrew Language & Usage]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: What does our presence look like on Twitter?  (I'm not there.)  Are new questions auto-tweeted or something like that?  I just want to know that we're sending them somewhere useful before voting. :-)

Comment: Pleasing to the eye, but it doesn't communicate anything to me.

Comment: It's in the same vein as the other twitter promotion ads: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dof9P.png

Comment: @Aarthi need a new one with the new logo.

Comment: @Naftali Done! :)

Comment: @Aarthi Nice! :-). Side point:  it should be a new post... It is unfair to capitalize on the votes of old...

Comment: @Naftali I'd normally agree, but in this case, the change was updating the old ad to match the new site design. :)

Comment: @Naftali Done. `;-)`

Comment: @msh210 what is done?

Comment: @Naftali, what you proposed: a new one with the new logo. See [my edit to this answer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/568/revisions).

Comment: @msh210 I am quite confused...

Comment: @Naftali, forget I mentioned anything.

Comment: @msh210 ... ok, but what did you change?

Comment: The Twitter icon.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Jog your curiosity: A new challenge every week. Click for details.]

Comment: From: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/562/719

Comment: +1 as I like it, but I think I'd like it even better if there were more of a contrast between the text in the foreground and the text in the background (as the latter distracts some from the former) (e.g., make the background more faded).

Comment: @msh210 I shall fade more. one minute ^_^

Comment: Oh, and "Shidducim" should probably be "Shidduchim".

Comment: @msh210 ahh nice spelling catch, one sec (i fixed the fading, how is it?)

Comment: @msh210 I fixed the spelling :-)

Comment: I see a checkerboard pattern as part of the background. Is that just me?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I think that is just you

Comment: OK, good. I can't see imgur content at work, so I open it using http://pixlr.com/editor/ . Something must have gotten lost in translation.

Comment: @IsaacMoses haha you are seeing it like that because of the transparent background ^_^. Put a white background behind it and you will see how it really looks :-D

Comment: Naftali, do you think you ought to give it a white background of its own? On this site, it'll be backed by the "sketchy" light-blue graph paper background and may look strange.

Comment: Also, some of us override CSS to get colors we can see more easily.  I use reverse video; if you're using dark text I wouldn't see your ad.  (I can't view the image from work either, so specific commenting/voting will wait until I get home tonight.)

Comment: Naftali: it looks good to me now! -- though I guess you should address the transparency issue raised by Monica Cellio. @IsaacMoses, I'm not seeing the sketchy background through the image.

Comment: @msh210, me neither, in a screenshot Naftali [provided](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2830106#2830106) in chat.

Comment: @Naftali - I too can't read the text. Could you maybe lose the calendar grid? I think the ad is a bit busy, and will look very simple and classy with just a mostly-opaque box behind the text.

Comment: @Naftali, I think the grid is fine, but the background is making it hard for me to read the text above the calendar part.  Can you lighten up the background image?

Comment: @MonicaCellio which background image? look through the edits (there are a few versions)

Comment: @neilfein the calendar grid was requested here: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/602/719

Comment: @Naftali, I won't be able to see the images again until I get home tonight, but I was talking about the version that was in place when I commented, and specifically about the background that's "behind" the grid (looks like a sefer torah?).  The dark parts of the background interfere with the black text above the calendar, at least for me.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think the torah behind adds something. maybe make it lighter? the text of the ad a diff color? what do u think?

Comment: @Naftali, I definitely agree that it adds something; I think making it lighter would improve it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I made it a bit lighter.

Comment: @Naftali, thanks.  That's better.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4424815#4424815

Comment: @msh210 That is not my fault that there is no more challenge. You are a moderator, you can propose one.....

Comment: @Naftali, I didn't say it's your fault. And anyone can propose one. There seems to be little interest, and I don't want to push it if the community's uninterested. I suggested dropping this from the lineup of ads not because it's a bad ad (it's good) but because it's advertising something that doesn't exist and shouldn't be advertised. I certainly meant no offense to you.

Comment: @msh210 If I understand correctly, the challenge ended when we stopped using system messages and nobody bothered checking meta. Now we have another means of coordinating users, so we could try this again sometime in the future.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, excellent point.

Comment: Voting down because it currently links to a blank page, which is a bit of a silly thing for an ad to do.

Answer (score 4):

[image: HebrewBooks.org]

Comment: Perhaps a description in the image?

Comment: @DoubleAA, can you think of good wording?

Comment: How about a time-insensitive variation on the text they have at the top of the home page? "Over 50,000 Classical Hebrew Books for Free Download"