# Can we in some way promote the Hebrew learning SE?

Tags: discussion

I think it would be helpful for us to sometimes cross reference or send questions to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language-usage

Is there a way we can promote it?

Answer (score 4):

You could nominate its ad to be in our [Community Promotion Ads](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/567/community-promotion-ads-2012) queue. You can get the ad image, link, and text by clicking "Share This" on the Area51 proposal.

Comment: Thanks done. How does it go into the rotation?

Comment: @avi once it gets +6 net votes, it will automatically go into the rotation.

Comment: Btw, yous should try to get people who own Judaica stores to post ads as well.