# RFP: Mi Yodeya Referencer Community Ad

Tags: discussion, advertising, user-scripts, referencer

A while back, with Hashem's help, the community came together to create the [Mi Yodeya Referencer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/mi-yodeya-referencer-a-syntax-for-linking-to-sources). If you're on this Meta reading this question, chances are you've heard of it.

But others may not have. That's why some have suggested (HT: [@Menachem](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9434?m=11996768#11996768) and [@MonicaCellio](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9434?m=10142191#10142191)) creating a [Community Promotion Ad](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1414/community-promotion-ads-2013) for MYR. This would increase exposure and, hopefully, use of the script, and all the good things that leads to. (Easier use of the site, better quality posts, wtvr.)

But! Creating a Community Ad requires some talent, and an eye for design. So @IsaacMoses suggested creating this here RFP (Request For Picture), in hopes that a talented Mi Yodeyan would create a nice-looking Community Ad.

---

**If you can design an ad, we can really use your skills!**

Content of the ad is flexible. There was some discussion [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12028837#12028837) about what it should say and show, but ultimately, we're aiming for conciseness and intuitiveness. A new user should be able to understand what MYR does before clicking on the ad.

If you're interested, feel free to solicit further comments/suggestions in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9434/discussion-and-debugging-for-mi-yodeya-userscripts). If you'd like, you can post drafts there for review/discussion. Then, when you're ready:

**Post your creation<sup>*</sup> as an answer to the [Community Promotion Ad](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1414/community-promotion-ads-2013) post.**  The clickthrough URL should be to the [Mi Yodeya Referencer post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/mi-yodeya-referencer-a-syntax-for-linking-to-sources).

---

<sup>* Following the [Community Ad requirements](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4205/community-promotion-ads-2017))</sup>

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1849

Comment: Completed ad, compliant with the updated requirements for community ads: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4233/5323