# bookmarked conversations should include more metadata

Tags: feature-request, chat

It would be nice if each [bookmarked chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468/jewish-life-and-learning?tab=conversations) would indicate, in the sidebar (where it lists the participants),

- the number of posts and
- the length of time from start to end.

The former is useful specifically in comparing periodically repeated chats (like [our Parashat Hashavu'a Chat](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520)), and the latter is of general interest.

**EDIT:** It was just pointed out to me that while the conversation page's sidebar doesn't contain the information aforementioned, the page that lists bookmarked conversations *does* contain it. So this feature request (to have the metadata in the conversation page itself) is much weaker than I thought. In fact, I don't particularly want the requested feature any longer, and would [downvote](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences) the request, myself, if I could. I won't delete the request, though, as perhaps others want the feature.

Comment: If someone else does indeed want this feature, please ping me here, and I'll re-open it.