# Volunteer needed: Host Parashat Hashavua' Chat

Tags: discussion, chat

Until recently, I usually served as unofficial host for the [Parashat Hashavua' Chat](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/parashat-hashavua-chat). Unfortunately, it seems that for the foreseeable future, I won't be able to attend. Would you be willing to take over this job, to help keep the Chat running smoothly?

No one's going to be able to do it every single week. We need someone who can do it some weeks, and who can take responsibility for finding someone to do it on others.

Here are the administrative tasks I would usually do:

- Welcome incoming chatters.
- Post `**Begin Parashat Hashavua' Chat #NN - PARASHANAME 57YY**` at 17:30 UTC.
- Post `**End Parashat Hashavua' Chat #NN - PARASHANAME 57YY**` when conversation lulls soon after 18:30 UTC.
- When conversation really stops, bookmark `Parashat Hashavua' Chat #NN - PARASHANAME 57YY` from the first stirrings of conversation to the last.
- Update the "latest transcript" link on the Chat [landing page](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/parashat-hashavua-chat).

In addition, whoever takes over as host would get to handle [stuff like](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/parashat-hashavua-chat#comment1134_520) adjusting times for DST and canceling specific weeks' chats due to holidays.

Comment: Note though that [to bookmark a chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#permalink) one needs 100 reputation points (seemingly, across all Stack Exchange sites).

Comment: @msh210, thanks. The same limit applies for editing the community wiki post that is the Chat's landing page. If anyone who hasn't yet met this threshold is interested in this position, though, I'd be very surprised.

Comment: Since no one's stepped up, I can do it this week (i.e., today). This is not a permanent solution, though.

Comment: @msh210, Ata ha-ish. Thanks. I recommend that you promote this request during today's chat.

Comment: Thanks, _ani mishtadel_.